# R read.csv how NOT to convert numbers into numerical values but keep them as strings

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I have a CSV file with all values in double quotes. One column is the id column and it contains values such as this:

```
01100170109835
```

The problem I am having is that no matter what options I specify (`as.is=T`, `stringsAsFactors=F`, or `numerals='no.loss'`), it always reads this id column in as numeric and drops the leading 0's. This is such a fundamental operation that I am really baffled that I can't find a solution.

Comment: Is there a way you could reproduce the problem?

Comment: You could try the `colClasses` argument in `read.csv`. Something like `read.csv("myfile.csv", colClasses = "character")`

Comment: Have you tried using `colClasses` to specify the variable types? It takes a vector that needs to be the same length as `ncol` in the data frame you're creating.

Comment: @jeremycg and ulfelder: thanks for the tip. That solves it.